# how to make input type="password" show value after input or 1s later

Tags: javascript, html

I need an effect like this

[image]

The number will change to "*" after  input a number or 1s later, and I also could get the password after change.

Comment: SO doesn't work this way. We're not here to develop stuff for you. You have to try something, give us some code and we'll help you debug it and make it work. But you just can't come and say "Hey guys, do this for me please"

Comment: Hi now used to this http://www.sitepoint.com/examples/password/MaskedPassword/demo.html

Comment: I just need an idea.

Comment: this is what i need，thanks @RohitAzad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a sample example of handling the keyUp event

[w3 example](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/event_keyup.asp)

Comment: Thanks,it not mapping,but I  got an idea from it!

Answer (score 1):

Get your acceptance criteria corrected. Problem title

> how to make input type="password" show value after input or 1s later

and in description you are expecting

> The number will change to "*" after input a number or 1s later, and I
>   also could get the password after change.

Anyway going by problem title, I am making the changes 
You can use `setTimeout` & `keyup`.I guess you are using jQuery

HTML

```
<div>
<input type = "password" id ="ipVal">
</div>
```

JS

```
(function(){
    $("#ipVal").on('keyup',function(){
      setTimeout(function(){
       $("#ipVal").prop('type','text')

      },1000)
    })
    }())
```

[WORKING DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/vasi_32/6syubLty/2/)

Answer (score 0):

Use jquery `keyup()` function, using this change the value to *, On the other end save value of it on different hidden value...